# Hibernate JPA Join Query jpql Issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this problem when I execute a select:

My StackTrace is :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:394)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3769)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3555)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3433)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:250)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
>     org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:104)
>     org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:79)
>     org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
>     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:222)
>     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:200)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1703)
>     org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
>     com.agostino.CrudJpa.selezione(CrudJpa.java:27)
>     com.agostino.Gioia.doGet(Gioia.java:43)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

My classes are:

```
@Entity
public class Persona {

@Id
private int id;
private String nome;
private String cognome;
private String numero;
private String dataora;

get and set...
```

and

```
@Entity
public class LinkTable implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String clientid;

@Id
private int id;

private String cid;
private String dataora;

get and set...
```

My query is

```
 String query="SELECT t FROM Persona t JOIN t.id s";
```

when I use

```
query="SELECT t FROM Persona t";
```

Everything is ok!

I use the file persistence.xml

Comment: What do you expect this query to do? What would a join between a tabe and one of its int column mean?

Comment: I want to do a join between the Persona table and LinkTable table on LinkTable Persona.id = LinkTable.id

Comment: Then you nee an association between Persona and LinkTable. Read the Hibernate manual.